# Django rest framework - permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Не могу понять в чём ошибка. Есть объект Post у него есть owner, хочу с помощью кастомной permission проверять это при удаление объекта пользователем.

**permissions**

```
class IsAuthorEntry(BasePermission):
"""
Проверяем автора объекта
"""
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    print('\nCheck 1\n')
    print(request)
    print(view)
    print(obj)
    return obj.owner == request.user or obj.entry.group.founder == request.user
```

**views**

```
class PostViewset(CreateUpdateDestroy, ListRetrieveMixins, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
"""
CRUD Поста
"""
permission_classes_by_action = {'delete': [IsAuthorEntry],
                                }

def get_permissions(self):
    print('\n\tPermissions\n')
    try:
        print('\tPermissions: ', self.permission_classes_by_action)
        # return permission_classes depending on `action`
        return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes_by_action[self.action]]
    except KeyError:
        # action is not set return default permission_classes
        return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]


def perform_destroy(self, instance):
    """
    """
    print('\n\tPerform destroy', instance)

def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    """
    print('\n\n\tDestroy here\n\n')

    instance = self.get_object()
    print('\tPost object: ', instance, '\n\tRequest user: ', self.request.user)
    author_per = self.check_object_permissions(self.request, instance)
```

Здесь не понимаю почему не работает и возвращает None

```
    print(f'\tAuthor permission: {author_per}')
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам надо permission сделать вот такого вида:

```
class IsAuthorEntry(BasePermission):
"""
Проверяем автора объекта
"""
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

    if obj.owner == request.user or obj.entry.group.founder == request.user:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

а потом в views:

```
class PostViewset(CreateUpdateDestroy, ListRetrieveMixins, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
"""
CRUD Поста
"""
permission_classes = (IsAuthorEntry, )
```

Comment: так разве permission_classes не на всю вьюху распространяется? @Ihar

Comment: @TheNoName на всю, а вам как надо?

Comment: Да, я понял уже, так и надо спасибо за решение! @Ihar